# Responsive website: move header nav from top to bottom problems

Tags: css, responsive-design, positioning, fixed, nav

While rebuilding the portfolio website I was making to be more responsive-oriented, I stumbled across a problem.
You see, I have a navigation menu at the top of the screen, but I want to place that navigation at the bottom of the screen when it's viewed on a smartphone.

Normally, since it's a header with a nav element in it that's `fixed` to the top left corner of the screen, I'd just give it a rule in my media query for (in this case) iPhones.

I'd change the top to top:none; (which I don't think is valid anyhow) and add a bottom: 0; so the rule for the navigation menu would become `bottom: 0;` and `left: 0;` instead of `top: 0;` and `left: 0;`.

Oddly enough I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

Below is my CSS:

```
    /* this is inside @media all */
header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #108ac2;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(16,138,194,0.76);
    background:#fff;
    opacity:.9;
}

header nav {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
    /* this is inside @media screen and (max-width: 480px)  */
header {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0!important;
    left:0!important;
}

header nav {
    width:90%;
    margin:0;
    height:80px;
}
```

You can also view the test site I'm building this on here: [my test portfolio](http://www.jorendegraaf.nl/testbed/testing.html).

I'd appreciate your help. I bet this has been asked before, but I really can't find it on here...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your css is applied for @media screen it will carry on and apply the @media all as well. I think this is causing the problem. So I added css for top of the header and margin on the body, and that seemed to do the job.

```
    /* this is inside @media all */
header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #108ac2;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(16,138,194,0.76);
    background:#fff;
    opacity:.9;
}

header nav {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
    /* this is inside @media screen and (max-width: 480px)  */
header {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0!important;
    left:0!important;
    top: initial;
}

header nav {
    width:90%;
    margin:0;
    height:80px;
}
body {
    margin:0 0 100px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It does seem to do the job. Styling of my links aside, it sticks to the bottom like it should.
I've never heard of `initial` before, though. Is it supported in most recent browsers?

Comment: Yeah, it is just the default setting for top. You just needed it to overwrite setting it to 0 in @media all.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm so going to use this technique more often now I know about it.

Comment: By the way, I just started with media queries and am not using the `@media all` statement anymore. 
I've become more specific like I should've done in the first place (like `@media screen and (...) etc`). 
Just to add to this post. It was more to experiment with it that I used `all`.